# Find the last sequence of occurance of a value in a time series data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have per minute time series data for 10 days with three columns: `time stamp`, `category`, `alarm`. Given a date, I want to `groupby` category and find the `timestamps` for which the alarm was set to 1 consecutively before the given date and create a `dataframe` from this subset.

```
   'Category'       'Date'              'Alarm'
0      A        1999-11-10 12:01:00        1
1      A        1999-11-10 12:02:00        1
2      A        1999-11-10 12:03:00        1
3      A        1999-11-10 12:04:00        1
4      A        1999-11-10 12:05:00        0
5      A        1999-11-10 12:06:00        0
.
.
.
1101   A        1999-11-13 10:07:00        1
1102   A        1999-11-13 10:08:00        1
1103   A        1999-11-13 10:09:00        1
1104   B        1999-11-23 13:09:00        0
1105   B        1999-11-23 13:10:00        0
1106   B        1999-11-23 13:11:00        1
1107   B        1999-11-23 13:12:00        1
1108   B        1999-11-23 13:13:00        1
1109   B        1999-11-23 13:14:00        0
.
.
.
. 
2110   B        1999-11-26 13:13:00        0
2110   B        1999-11-26 13:14:00        0
2110   B        1999-11-26 13:15:00        1 
2111   B        1999-11-26 13:16:00        1 
2112   B        1999-11-26 13:17:00        1 
2113   B        1999-11-26 13:18:00        1 
2114   B        1999-11-26 13:19:00        1
2115   B        1999-11-26 13:20:00        0
2116   B        1999-11-26 13:21:00        0
2117   C        1999-12-02 17:11:00        1 
.
.    
.
```

I would like the output to be a new dataframe which has only these rows:

```
     'Category'       'Date'              'Alarm'
 1101   A        1999-11-13 10:07:00        1
 1102   A        1999-11-13 10:08:00        1
 1103   A        1999-11-13 10:09:00        1
 2110   B        1999-11-23 13:15:00        1 
 2111   B        1999-11-23 13:16:00        1 
 2112   B        1999-11-23 13:17:00        1 
 2113   B        1999-11-23 13:18:00        1 
 2114   B        1999-11-23 13:19:00        1
```

i.e, the rows in each group with the last consecutive sequence of 1s in alarm.
What I have tried:

```
df.groupby('category')['alarm'].apply(lambda x: x==1)
```

But this gives all the rows which have alarm as 1 and not just the last sequence of consecutive 1. Any directions on how to get this is appreciated. Thanks! :)

Edit 1: I just provided a subset of the dataframe.The the last consecutive sequence of 1s can occur any number of days before (e.g, if the timeseries is from Nov 1- Nov 10, for a category the last consecutive 1s could have occurred on nov 2 or nov 8. And the length of the 1s can also vary.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try

```
# convert to datetime type
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# blocks of consecutive `1`:
s = (1-df.Alarm).cumsum()*df.Alarm

# last group of `1` within Category and day:
last_groups = s.groupby(df.Category).transform('max')

# output:
df[s==last_groups]
```

Ooutput:

```
     Category                Date  Alarm
1101        A 1999-11-13 10:07:00      1
1102        A 1999-11-13 10:08:00      1
1103        A 1999-11-13 10:09:00      1
2110        B 1999-11-26 13:15:00      1
2111        B 1999-11-26 13:16:00      1
2112        B 1999-11-26 13:17:00      1
2113        B 1999-11-26 13:18:00      1
2114        B 1999-11-26 13:19:00      1
2117        C 1999-12-02 17:11:00      1
```

Comment: Superb answer, very nice!

Comment: I don't believe the last row belongs in the output however

Comment: Thanks! But this picks up the consecutive sequences before as well and not just the last one. I'm not looking for consecutive 1s within each day, just whenever the last sequence is. It could be before any number of days.

Comment: Drop `df.date.normalized` inside groupby and you should get one sequence for each id.

Comment: I still get the same result. Can you please explain the code a bit?

Comment: I updated the answer to show the out come with your new sample data. You should play with the sample data only, print `s` to see what it marks, and do the same thing with `last_groups`.

Comment: I checked that. Since both the series s and last groups returns the same indices(all indices where alarm =1), so I asked if you could explain the code a bit. It still returns all the indices and not just the last sequence of consecutive 1s.

Comment: `last_groups` looks at `s` within each category (`groupby(df.Cateogry)`) and get the max values, which supposedly should be the last group of `1` within each category. Please refer to my output above, in which I don't see any other sequences except for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Make date into datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Get rid of time part
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Taking rolling sum of Alarms
k = df.groupby('Day')['Alarm'].rolling(3).sum().reset_index()
# Take last set of consecutive 3's per day
k = k[k['Alarm']==3].groupby('Day').last()
# Capture the index of each row in the original data frame
k = k['level_1'].values
# Drop day column
df.drop(columns=['Day'], inplace=True)
# Join the rows together
df = pd.concat([df.loc[x-2:].head(3) for x in k])
```

Output

```
 Category                Date  Alarm
6         A 1999-11-10 12:07:00      1  
7         A 1999-11-10 12:08:00      1  
8         A 1999-11-10 12:09:00      1 
15        B 1999-11-23 13:15:00      1 
16        B 1999-11-23 13:16:00      1  
17        B 1999-11-23 13:17:00      1
```